# swipe left, right, up and down depending on velocity or other variables 

Tags: java, android, velocity, gesture, swipe

i've got a class extended from simple on gesture and i'm working with the onfling method:

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float e1_X = e1.getX();
        float e1_Y = e1.getY();
        float e2_X = e1.getX();
        float e2_Y = e2.getY();
        if(velocityX > 0 && velocityX > velocityY){
            text.setText("Swipe left");
        }else if(velocityX < 0 && velocityX < velocityY){
            text.setText("Swipe right");
        }else if(velocityY < 0 && velocityX > velocityY){
            text.setText("Swipe down");
        }else if(velocityY > 0 && velocityX < velocityY){
            text.setText("Swipe up");
        }
        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

I know it depends on certain angles but i can't do it, i tried with the velocityX, and velocityY, it's working only if you do it precisely . But what i want is an angle of "mistake" : if you swipe diagonally for example up and right i need to choose which is the good way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check speed and distance. Here is an example of horizontal swipe detector. You can add vertical detection in the same manner.

```
public class HSwipeDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2, final float velocityX, final float velocityY) {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {  return false;  }

        /* positive value means right to left direction */
        final float distance = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
        final boolean enoughSpeed = Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
        if(distance > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && enoughSpeed) {
            // right to left swipe
            onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }  else if (distance < -SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && enoughSpeed) {
            // left to right swipe
            onSwipeRight();
            return true;
        } else {
            // oooou, it didn't qualify; do nothing
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onSwipeLeft() { 
        // do your stuff here
    }

    protected void onSwipeRight() {   
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, i know but i was hoping to swipe up and down to, before putting those condition. It's helping me but this not the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Comparing VelocityX against VelocityY in case of diagonal swipe is the same as comparing distanceX against distanceY (because velocity is derived from distance). Velocity is measure of energy of the swipe move. In order to do your stuff you need to analyse distances, and use velocity only as a threshold to see was the user's move quick enough to qualify as a swipe.

Comment: Okay so the thing i needed to use is the SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH. This variable is used to see if the user is swiping vertically or horizontally . I found something at this [link](http://blog.blackmoonit.com/2010/07/gesture-detection-swipe-detection_4292.html)

Comment: @JBM: Can you say me on how to calculate "SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY" value?

Comment: Just figure out the value that suits you best. In my case it was 200. I your case it can be less or more, depending on the desired level of responsiveness. Just try and figure for yourself.

It's a good idea, by the way, to convert pixels into dips before calculations. That will make it stable across different screens with different densities.

Comment: I believe the solution above only works if you fling your view from its original position. For instance, if the original position of your view is in a middle of the parent view and, first you scroll all the way to the right and then apply a little fling to the left, this code will assume a swipe right since the distance will be negative, however, I think it's fair to still assume a swipe left.

Comment: @JBM Can you elaborate that on which object this gesture is working on? Means either on clicking on the image or text?