# ItemTouchHelper: How to prevent "fling" swipes until finger passes swipe threshold?

Tags: android, callback, swipe, velocity, itemtouchhelper

**Context:** I'm implementing ItemTouchHelper with swipe actions (Date, Complete, Delete, Settings). I have `getSwipeThreshold()` return .2f. This means I need to *drag* horizontally 2/10 of the way to swipe. I made it so that passing that threshold would change the background state (e.g. Complete view). Going farther, 4/10 of the way, would change it again (e.g. Date view). These changes are only called during `isCurrentlyActive()` (i.e. when the user
s finger is touching the item). See code below.

```
        public float getSwipeThreshold(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            return .2f;
        }


        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, ((SwipeableHolder) viewHolder).getSwipeableView(), dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

            if (isCurrentlyActive) {
                SwipeAdapter.SwipeableHolder holder = (SwipeAdapter.SwipeableHolder)viewHolder;
                float swipeFraction = dX / viewHolder.itemView.getWidth();

                // Far Left
                if (swipeFraction > 0.4f) {
                    mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_DATE;
                    holder.setSwipeState(SWIPE_STATE_DATE);

                    // Close Left
                } else if (swipeFraction > 0.2f){
                    mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_COMPLETE;
                    holder.setSwipeState(SWIPE_STATE_COMPLETE);

                    // Far Right
                } else if (swipeFraction < -0.4f) {
                    mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_SETTINGS;
                    holder.setSwipeState(SWIPE_STATE_SETTINGS);

                    // Close Right
                } else if (swipeFraction < -0.2f) {
                    mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_DELETE;
                    holder.setSwipeState(SWIPE_STATE_DELETE);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Problem:** While dragging works properly, flinging doesn't. When I *fling* and lift my finger BEFORE the threshold, it will swipe prematurely due to the velocity. The problem is the background doesn't change unless my finger passes the threshold.

***Question:*** How do I prevent fling from starting a swipe until my finger passes the swipe threshold?

(Or perhaps I'm asking the wrong question and there is a better way to synchronize flinging with the swipe threshold and thus changing the background state at the right time?)

Comment: You can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html), Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720138/swipe-left-right-up-and-down-depending-on-velocity-or-other-variables)

Comment: Hello @SaravInfern, did you find the solution using an ItemTouchHelper?

Answer (score 0):

You can control how much your view should be swiped by dividing dX parameter as per your need. If it's full dX, it will swipe fully and exit, if it's less, then it will swipe to that value only horizontally.
See below for if you want to swipe one fourth of the width:

```
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, ((SwipeableHolder) viewHolder).getSwipeableView(), dX/4, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
```